# MongoDb: documents with variable structure using and C#

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver, nancy

I have a HTML form that creates documents with a dynamic structure. 
Here below some samples of the data inserted by the users.

A very simple document

```
{
"name" : "Simple element",
"notes" : "Lorem ipsum rocks",
"values" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "An array with 2 values",
        "value" : [ 100,200],
        "editable" : true
    }
]
```

}

And more complex document

```
{
"name" : "Complex element",
"notes" : "Lorem ipsum rocks",
"values" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "A text value",
        "value" : "ABCDEF",
        "editable" : true
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "A numeric value",
        "value" : 100,
        "editable" : false
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "A array of 4 values",
        "value" : [1,2,3,4],
        "editable" : false
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "A matrix 2x4",
        "value" : [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],
        "editable" : false
    }
]
```

}

The documents must be saved in MongoDB using C# MongoCharp driver and NancyFX.
At the moment the POST is implemented in this way but I'm not sure if this the correct way to handle object with a dynamic structure

```
Post["/api/docs"] = _ =>
{
  //looking for better solution
  var json = Request.Body.AsString();
  var item = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
  database.GetCollection("docs").Insert(item);
  return new Response { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created };
};
```

but can't find a good solution for the GET method

```
Get["/api/docs"] = _ =>
{
  //looking for solution
};
```

What do you think would be the best solution for this scenario?

Comment: How do you want to query the documents? What field do you want to query on?

Comment: I want to get back the list of documents filtered by a property (eg. name) or a single document by _id

Comment: And how will you know what property to filter on? Query string?

Comment: I need to add a Category property at the top level of the JSON object. Then I'll filter by category with something like `Get["/api/docs/:category"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to return the document from MongoDB as json try something like this

```
Get["/api/docs/{category}"] = _ =>
{
   var filterValue = _.category;
   //Search the DB for one record where the category property matches the filterValue
   var item = database.GetCollection("docs").FindOne(Query.EQ("category", filterValue))
   var json = item.ToJson();

   var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json );
   return new Response
   {
      ContentType = "application/json",
      Contents = s => s.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length)
   };
};
```

Comment: returning JSON form MongoDB is an option. I also found a way to map the sample JSON docs in a C# object

Answer (score 2):

There's also another way to solve the problem. Let's call it "the strongly typed solution". I've created two POCO objects

```
public class DocumentItem
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public String Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Notes { get; set; }

    public SubItem[] Values { get; set; }

}

public class SubItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Boolean Editable { get; set; }

    public Object Value { get; set; }
}
```

than in the module the read data is implemented as shown below

```
    Get["/api/docs/{id}"] = p => database.GetCollection<DocumentItem>("docs")
            .FindOne(Query<DocumentItem>.EQ(x => x.Id, (string)p.id));

    Get["/api/docs"] = _ => database.GetCollection<DocumentItem>("docs")
            .FindAll()
            .ToList();
```

and I can use binding for the insert in this way

```
   Post["/api/docs"] = _ =>
   {
      var item = this.Bind<DocumentItem>();
      database.GetCollection("docs").Insert(item);
      return item;
   };
```